# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in Angular with Interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror, interceptor

I have an Interceptor to catch http errors when calling my RESTful service:

```
services.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('globalInterceptor');

    var elementsList = $();

    // this message will appear for a defined amount of time and then vanish again
    var showMessage = function(content, cl, time) {
        $('<div/>')
            .addClass(cl)
            .hide()
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .delay(time)
            .fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).remove(); })
            .appendTo(elementsList)
            .text(content);
    };
});

services.factory('globalInterceptor', function($q){
    //When the interceptor runs, it is passed a promise object
    return function(promise){

        //In an interceptor, we return another promise created by the .then function.
        return promise.then(function(successResponse){
            //Do your code here if the response was successful
            if (typeof(successResponse) !== 'undefined') {
                if (successResponse.config.method.toUpperCase() != 'GET') {
                    showMessage('Success', 'http-success-message', 5000);
                    return successResponse;
                }
            }
        }, function(errorResponse){
            switch (errorResponse.status) {
                case 400: // if the status is 400 we return the error
                    showMessage(errorResponse.data.message, 'http-error-message', 6000);
                    // if we have found validation error messages we will loop through
                    // and display them
                    if(errorResponse.data.errors.length > 0) {
                        for(var i=0; i<errorResponse.data.errors.length; i++) {
                            showMessage(errorResponse.data.errors[i],
                                'http-error-validation-message', 6000);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 401: // if the status is 401 we return access denied
                    showMessage('Wrong email address or password!',
                        'http-error-message', 6000);
                    break;
                case 403: // if the status is 403 we tell the user that authorization was denied
                    showMessage('You have insufficient privileges to do what you want to do!',
                        'http-error-message', 6000);
                    break;
                case 500: // if the status is 500 we return an internal server error message
                    showMessage('Internal server error: ' + errorResponse.data.message,
                        'http-error-message', 6000);
                    break;
                default: // for all other errors we display a default error message
                    showMessage('Error ' + errorResponse.status + ': ' + errorResponse.data.message,
                        'http-error-message', 6000);
            }

            return $q.reject(errorResponse);
        });
    }
});
```

My login-page halts when loading. The problem came after making the inceptor, before that everything was working fine.

It gives me this error message that really don't help:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:7479:22
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:10655:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:10655:81)
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:10741:26
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:11634:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:11479:31)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:11740:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:7744:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:7918:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-1.2.2/angular.js:7874:11) angular.js:9159
```

I've tried to debug/console.log this "data" attribute but can't locate it...
When the app loads, it gets two files OK (200 and with data attr) and two of these errors.

Any help would be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: What your server returns on 400 error?

Comment: It actually returns a 500! Its the standard error for REST services (internal server error). I only change my HTTP respond code on certain exceptions (database errors etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your **function(errorResponse)**.
It seems to pass the error along the chain correctly.

But I have a problem with your **function(successResponse)**.
It passes the value down the chain only when two IF statements are fulfilled in other cases it passed undefined.

My guess is that you need to add $q.reject() at the end of your **function(successResponse)**.

Comment: I solved it by using a Interceptor instead of a ResponseInterceptor which is deprecated...